# Is there a way to add timestamp to KSQL stream select?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have some message processing using ksql streams and I'd like to add timestamp to each processed row, as to retrieve time of finished processing.

Initially I've assumed the ROWTIME would end up getting updated, but it seems that it gets retained from the initial Kafka topic's message.

TIMESTAMP methods seems to be used for converting input data into some specific timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a new UDF to get the timestamp and add it to the result. For more information on how to write UDFs for KSQL refer to the following page: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html